# Creating Cuda dll and using it on VC++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, cuda

I have a CUDA project in visual studio 2012 containing a function that I want to use it in a VC++ project thanks to Mr.Crovella I changed my CUDA project target from **.exe** to **.dll**  in **project properties/Configuration Properties/General/Configuration Type**. here is my header file defining my function:

kernel.h

```
#ifndef KERNEL_H
#define KERNEL_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif

void __declspec(dllexport) cuspDsolver(int *rowOffset, int *colIndex, double *values , double *X, double *rhs, int size, int nnz);

#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif

#endif
```

and here is my function implementation:

kernel.cu

```
#include "kernel.h"
#include <cusp/krylov/cg.h>
#include <cusp/csr_matrix.h>
#include <cusp/hyb_matrix.h>
#include <cusp/gallery/poisson.h>
#include <cusp/io/matrix_market.h>
#include <cusp\print.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;


void cuspDsolver(int *rowOffset, int *colIndex, double *values , double *X, double *rhs, int size, int nnz)
{
    cusp::csr_matrix<int,double,cusp::device_memory> A(size,size,nnz);
    for (int i = 0; i < (size+1); i++)
    {
        A.row_offsets[i] = rowOffset[i];
    }
        for (int i = 0; i < nnz; i++)
    {
        A.column_indices[i] = colIndex[i];
        A.values[i] = values[i];
    }
    cusp::array1d<double,cusp::device_memory> XX(size,0.);
    cusp::array1d<double,cusp::device_memory> B(size,0.);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        B[i] = rhs[i];
    }

    cusp::krylov::cg(A,XX,B);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        X[i] = XX[i];
    }
}
```

and here is my VC++ project(it is a static library **system.lib** project which will be used in **quickMain.exe**) and how I tried to use my **.dll** file:

system.lib

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif

void __declspec ( dllimport ) cuspDsolver(int *rowOffset, int *colIndex, double *values , double *X, double *rhs, int size, int nnz);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
int 
ProfileSPDLinDirectSolver::solve(void){
.
.
.
.
cuspDsolver(rowOffset,colIndex,values,answer,rightHandSide,theSize,nnz);
.
.
.
.
}
```

when I want to build this project(I did copy my dll file to solution directory and and solution/Debug directory) I get these errors, would you please tell me if I did anything wrong on creating or using this dll?

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cuspDsolver referenced in function          "public: virtual int __thiscall ProfileSPDLinDirectSolver::solve(void)" (?     solve@ProfileSPDLinDirectSolver@@UAEHXZ)         2012\Projects\Ardalan_12\Win32\proj\quickMain\system.lib(ProfileSPDLinDirectSolver.obj)

error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Ardalan_12\Win32\bin\quickMain.exe 1
```

Comment: did you add the dll as a library to link against in your `system.lib` project definition ?

Comment: my problem solved thank you that was the problem, But I have another question, my function in "CUDA solution" was VERY fast but when I call this function converted to dll from VC++ project it's mysteriously slowو is this normal? I mean calling a function in dll is usually slow or there is another prolblem? thanks in advanced

Comment: It's difficult to say without knowing the scope of the timing you're referring to.  I wouldn't expect the dll mechanism to have a large impact on overall timing.  If your code runs in 100 milliseconds statically linked, and 200 milliseconds as a dll, I suppose that may be normal, I don't know exactly what windows dll overhead should be.  Anyway this seems like a different question than your linking question, and I would suggest posting a new SO question if you want help with it -- and provide more details.  Why don't you post an answer to explain what you did here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the dll is created from kernel.cu, you will have a dll library file (say, `kernel.dll`) and a dll library import file (say, `kernel.lib`) produced.

In your VC/VS project definition for any project that wishes to use that dll, you must link against the dll library import file:

```
nvcc ... -lkernel
```

The process of adding this library to your project definition is the same process you would use for adding any other library.  Make sure the `kernel.dll` and `kernel.lib` are on the linker paths you specify, also.

And, at runtime, your `kernel.dll` library will need to be either in the same directory as your executable or else in the windows dll load path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add __declspec(dllexport) modifier on the function declarations. This modifier tells the compiler and linker to export a function or variable from the DLL for use by other applications.
Add the followings to your kernel.h,

```
#pragma once

#ifdef KERNEL_EXPORTS
#define KERNEL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define KERNEL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" KERNEL_API void cuspDsolver(int *rowOffset, int *colIndex, double *values ,double *X, double *rhs, int size, int nnz);
```

For details, please reference to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=vs-2019#to-add-a-header-file-to-the-dll

Comment: Please include the main points from the associated link in the question itself, as external links can change or break over time. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem so this information would make it a better answer.